# webSocket push notification from spring boot to ionic

Tags: java, spring-boot, ionic-framework, websocket, push-notification

I'm kind of new to Spring Boot. I got thrown at a project and now I've to set a push notification from Spring Boot to Ionic.

I've a running test; every time the test is True a notification will be sent to the client. I already try it, but I didn't get the way to do it, so if anyone can help me with this I'll be thankful!

Comment: What is the meaning of push notification from spring boot to ionic? It should be to android /iPhone right?

Comment: yes yes i mean Android app with ionic

Answer (score 0):

Hello i propose to you onesignal , use onesignal very easy you need read this documentation : https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ionic-sdk-setup